# I have deployed kubernetes cluster. The issue i have is that the dashboard is not accessible from external desktop system

Tags: kubernetes, dashboard

I have deployed kubernetes cluster. The issue i have is that the dashboard is not accessible from external desktop system.

Following is my setup.
Two vm's with cluster deployed, one master one node.
dashboard running without any issue the kube-dns is also working as expected.
kubernetes version is 1.7.

Issue: When trying to access dashboard externally through kubectl proxy. i get unauthorized response.

This is with rbac role and rolebindings enabled.
How to i configure the cluster for http browser access to dashboard from external system.

Any hint/suggestions are most welcome.

Answer (score 1):

kubectl proxy not working > 1.7

try this:

copy ~/.kube/config file to your desktop
then run the kubect like this

```
  export POD_NAME=$(kubectl --kubeconfig=config get pods -n kube-system -l "app=kubernetes-dashboard,release=kubernetes-dashboard" -o jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.name}")
  echo http://127.0.0.1:9090/
  kubectl --kubeconfig=config -n kube-system port-forward $POD_NAME 9090:9090
```

Then access the ui like this: http://127.0.0.1:9090

see this helps

Answer (score 0):

If `kubectl proxy` gives the *Unauthorized* error, there can be 2 reasons:

1. Your user cert doesn't have the appropriate permissions. This is unlikely since you successfully deployed `kube-dns` and the dashboard.
2. kubelet authn/authz is enabled and it's not setup correctly. See the [answer to my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44541723/kubectl-exec-results-in-error-unable-to-upgrade-connection-unauthorized).