# kubectl exec "error: unable to upgrade connection: Unauthorized"

Tags: api, docker, kubernetes

I was using our Kubernetes cluster, I don't think so i have changed recently after deployment but am encountering this error

**Error kubectl log with verbose :**

```
01:49:42.691510   30028 round_trippers.go:444] Response Headers:
I0514 01:49:42.691526   30028 round_trippers.go:447]     Content-Length: 12
10514 01:49:42.691537   30028 round_trippers.go:447]     Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
                                                            I0514 01:49:42.691545   30028 round_trippers.go:447]     Date: Tue, 14 May 2019 08:49:42 GMT
                                                                                                                                                        F0514 01:49:42.691976   30028 helpers.go:119] error: unable to upgrade connection: 
 Unauthorized
```

**Kubelet running with below options :**

```
/usr/local/bin/kubelet --logtostderr=true --v=2 --address=0.0.0.0 --node-ip=1******
--hostname-override=***** --allow-privileged=true --bootstrap-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf --authentication-token-webhook --enforce-node-allocatable= --client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/ca.crt --pod-manifest-path=/etc/kubernetes/manifests --pod-infra-container-image=gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64:3.1 --node-status-update-frequency=10s --cgroup-driver=cgroupfs --max-pods=110 --anonymous-auth=false --read-only-port=0 --fail-swap-on=True --runtime-cgroups=/systemd/system.slice --kubelet-cgroups=/systemd/system.slice --cluster-dns=10.233.0.3 --cluster-domain=cluster.local --resolv-conf=/etc/resolv.conf --kube-reserved cpu=200m,memory=512M --node-labels=node-role.kubernetes.io/master=,node-role.kubernetes.io/node= --network-plugin=cni --cni-conf-dir=/etc/cni/net.d --cni-bin-dir=/opt/cni/bin
```

***API running with below options :***

```
kube-apiserver --allow-privileged=true --apiserver-count=2 --authorization-mode=Node,RBAC --bind-address=0.0.0.0 --endpoint-reconciler-type=lease --insecure-port=0 --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalDNS,InternalIP,Hostname,ExternalDNS,ExternalIP --runtime-config=admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1alpha1 --service-node-port-range=30000-32767 --storage-backend=etcd3 --advertise-address=******* --client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/ca.crt --enable-admission-plugins=NodeRestriction --enable-bootstrap-token-auth=true --etcd-cafile=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/etcd/ca.pem --etcd-certfile=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/etcd/node-bg-kub-dev-1.pem --etcd-keyfile=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/etcd/node-bg-kub-dev-1-key.pem --etcd-servers=https://*******:2379,https://********:2379,https://*****:2379 --kubelet-client-certificate=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/apiserver-kubelet-client.crt --kubelet-client-key=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/apiserver-kubelet-client.key --proxy-client-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/front-proxy-client.crt --proxy-client-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/front-proxy-client.key --requestheader-allowed-names=front-proxy-client --requestheader-client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/front-proxy-ca.crt --requestheader-extra-headers-prefix=X-Remote-Extra- --requestheader-group-headers=X-Remote-Group --requestheader-username-headers=X-Remote-User --secure-port=6443 --service-account-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/sa.pub --service-cluster-ip-range=10.233.0.0/18 --tls-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/apiserver.crt --tls-private-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/apiserver.key
```

Comment: i have already checked this thread but i already have those certificate arguments with api and kubelet service 
```https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44541723/kubectl-exec-results-in-error-unable-to-upgrade-connection-unauthorized```

Comment: Here's that link as a link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44541723/kubectl-exec-results-in-error-unable-to-upgrade-connection-unauthorized

Answer (score 1):

I think you messed your cert files or you played with RBAC profiles.

You can have a look at great guide by Kelsey Hightower called [kubernetes-the-hard-way](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way).

It's showing how to setup a whole cluster from beggining without any automation tools like kubeadm.

In part [04-certificate-authority - Provisioning a CA and Generating TLS Certificates](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way/blob/master/docs/04-certificate-authority.md).
You have exampled of certs being used in Kubernetes.

> #### The Kubelet Client Certificates
>
> Kubernetes uses a  [special-purpose authorization mode](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authorization/node/)  called Node Authorizer, that specifically authorizes API requests made by  [Kubelets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/components/#kubelet). In order to be authorized by the Node Authorizer, Kubelets must use a credential that identifies them as being in the  `system:nodes`  group, with a username of  `system:node:<nodeName>`. In this section you will create a certificate for each Kubernetes worker node that meets the Node Authorizer requirements.

Once certs are generated for workers and uploaded you need to generate kubeconfig for each worker.

> #### The kubelet Kubernetes Configuration File
>
> When generating kubeconfig files for Kubelets the client certificate matching the Kubelet's node name must be used. This will ensure Kubelets are properly authorized by the Kubernetes  [Node Authorizer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authorization/node/).

Also this case might be helpful ["kubectl exec" results in "error: unable to upgrade connection: Unauthorized"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44541723/kubectl-exec-results-in-error-unable-to-upgrade-connection-unauthorized)

Comment: Thanks for the guide.
Seemsam right, CA.pem will be same for all nodes inside cluster 
https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way/blob/master/docs/04-certificate-authority.md#distribute-the-client-and-server-certificates

Answer (score 0):

I got fixed this issue.

Actually  "/etc/kubernetes/ssl/ca.crt" in my both masters are same but in worker nodes "/etc/kubernetes/ssl/ca.crt" is totally different. So i just copied "/etc/kubernetes/ssl/ca.crt" from master to my worker nodes and restarted kubelet in workers  nodes which fixed my issue.
But am not sure I did right changes for fix

I hope --client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/ca.crt should be same for all kubelet which is running master and workers