# kubectl exec fails intermittently with error: unable to upgrade connection: Authorization error

Tags: kubernetes, authorization, kubectl

I am just trying to do kubectl exec to one of my pods. When I see the pod status, it is all fine. My worker nodes are also in a good state. But when I try '`kubectl exec`', it fails **intermittently** with the below error. Not able to understand why is this happening. We guessed it might be because of worker nodes, so we deployed all new worker nodes freshly. But still, see the issue.

```
error: unable to upgrade connection: Authorization error (user=cluster_admin, verb=create, resource=nodes, subresource=proxy)
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: did any answer listed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44312745/kubernetes-rbac-unable-to-upgrade-connection-forbidden-user-systemanonymous helped ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's not an issue of the Kubectl exec

it's failing due to **Authorization** issue.

Verify first access

```
kubectl auth can-i create pods/exec
```

> yes

```
kubectl auth can-i get pods/exec
```

> yes

If you have admin access with kubectl and getting output of commands, which mean you kubectl to API server connection is good.

It could be failing at **kubelet** level, as **kubelet** might be configured to Auth the all requests and API server is not providing the details.

You can read more about it at : https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/kubelet-authn-authz/#kubelet-authentication

API server uses the `--kubelet-client-certificate` and `--kubelet-client-key` flags for auth